# Is there a standard way to get the latest message in a kinesis shard?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have a use case where I want to pick up only the latest message in a Kinesis shard.

I looked into the LATEST starting point, but it will only pick up messages after the time of integration.

What I want is to only get the latest message in a shard.

There is an old question related to this : [How can I get the most recent record from an Amazon Kinesis stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346586/how-can-i-get-the-most-recent-record-from-an-amazon-kinesis-stream)

Not sure whether we still can not get the latest message from the stream.

If not, then would like to clear my understanding of AWS kinesis : It's a stream of data. So shouldn't we be able to pick up the latest message? If not, then how is this different from SQS?